# Check for nil gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have this line in my controller:

```
user = User.any_of({:user_name => login}, {:email => login})

if user.nil?
  # ...
elsif user.legacy_password.nil?
```

And it creates this error:

```
undefined method `legacy_password' for []:Array
```

Why would this happen? the user object is supposed to be `nil`. At least that is what the debugger said.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall what do you mean? Sorry I am a bit new to Ruby and Devise :)

Comment: Well, you have the variable `user`, what's the code where you define it?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I see, there is a line above with this:     user = User.any_of({:user_name => login},{:email => login})

Comment: Your supposition makes little sense. Your logic says _"Is this nil?"_ and the runtime says _"No"_, and then you say _"OK, call `legacy_password` on it"_ and the runtime says _"This thing, which happens to be an array, does not have a method named `legacy_password`."_ Your `nil?` calls are irrelevant to your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming your `any_of` method returns an array of results, not a single result. You probably want to add `.first` to the end of it, which will give you either a User record, or `nil` if `any_of` returned an empty array.

```
user = User.any_of({:user_name => login},{:email => login}).first
```

Comment: @DFylan thank you that helped!! I need 15 reputation points to up vote you and will accept the answer when the system allows me :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using mongoid (`#any_of`) and it's returning an array.

The error is because you are calling `legacy_password` on an array, but I assume it is defined on the User model.